# MySQL Getting Average number of latest dates

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Trying to get an average of number from a table based on the latest dates of each. It works, but really slow, 30 seconds. Main table has 5,782 rows, and is growing. Anyway to change this query and make it a bit faster?

```
SELECT AVG(l_temp) AS temp, AVG(l_hum) AS hum, MAX(l_timestamp) AS stamp FROM sensorlogs AS s1
    LEFT JOIN sensors s
      ON (s.s_id = s1.l_s_id)
    WHERE s.s_average = 1 AND s1.l_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(s2.l_timestamp) FROM sensorlogs AS s2 WHERE s2.l_s_id = s1.l_s_id)
```

Here is explain and my table:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | s | (NULL) | ALL | PRIMARY | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 2 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | s1 | (NULL) | ALL | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 5782 | 10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s2 | (NULL) | ALL | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 5782 | 10.00 | Using where |

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensorlogs` (
  `l_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `l_s_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `l_temp` decimal(20,1) NOT NULL,
  `l_hum` decimal(20,1) NOT NULL,
  KEY `l_timestamp` (`l_timestamp`),
  KEY `l_s_id` (`l_s_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
  `s_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_ident` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_created` date NOT NULL,
  `s_average` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s_alert` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s_thresh` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s_l_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_location` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Version: 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Your EXPLAIN shows "Using Block Nested Loop" which is typical if you don't have an index to support the join condition. Please show the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, and post in text, not as screenshots. It helps to show the indexes and constraints, if any, in addition to the columns. Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Also please run `SELECT VERSION();` and show the result.

Comment: Added info above, added indexes no change.

Comment: Both your Ubuntu and MySQL versions are way out of date! Did you try the composite index on ``(`l_s_id`, `l_timestamp`)``? It's certainly not included in your current `CREATE TABLE` statement. Please update your `EXPLAIN` output and include it as text, not an image.

Comment: I can't do an explain as text! So here is an image. No I did not do a composite index, I did two individual indexes, I updated to composite index together, same deal, no change. Version of MySQL makes no difference on the speed of this small query. https://cdn.microtronix-tech.com/imgs/Screenshot_at_2023-04-25_13-33-31.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT AVG(l_temp) AS temp, AVG(l_hum) AS hum, MAX(l_timestamp) AS stamp
FROM (
    SELECT l_s_id, MAX(l_timestamp) AS max_ts
    FROM sensorlogs
    GROUP BY l_s_id
) t
JOIN sensorlogs sl ON sl.l_s_id = t.l_s_id AND sl.l_timestamp = t.max_ts
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sensors WHERE s_average = 1 AND s_id = t.l_s_id);
```

It will still need the composite index on `` (`l_s_id`, `l_timestamp`) ``. As you do not have a PK on `sensorlogs`, you could make that index PK.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use
   `SELECT AVG(l_temp) AS temp, AVG(l_hum) AS hum, MAX(l_timestamp) AS stamp FROM sensorlogs AS s1 LEFT JOIN sensors s ON (s.s_id = s1.l_s_id) WHERE s.s_average = 1 AND s1.l_s_id = (SELECT s2.l_s_id FROM sensorlogs AS s2 GROUP BY s2.l_s_id ORDER BY s2.l_s_id DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Did you test this with MySQL? MySQL does not support `SELECT TOP 1 ...`. That's a Microsoft SQL Server specific syntax.

Comment: This query is super fast, but does it take into account multiple `l_s_id`'s coming back?

Comment: It's really not returning the correct temp average, it's too low. I think it's taking into account all records instead of only latest time of each id group.